# jquery function call inside click event

Tags: javascript, jquery

This is my javascript function. The issue is when I am calling the function inside the click event, its showing this error in Firefox, but nor in Chrome.

> ReferenceError: toDo is not defined

```
$(document.body).on("click", ".btnCheck", function(){
    if () {
        //do something
    } else {
        if (pcheck == "online") {
            // Doing some operations and function calling
            toDo();
        } else {
            toDo();  // function calling, HERE SHOWING ERROR IN FIREFOX 
            // ReferenceError: toDo is not defined
        }
    }
    function toDo () {
       //Do something
    }
});
```

Comment: The function should be moved outside of `click` handler.

Comment: see, but that case need to pass so many variables, because its function depends on some variables

Comment: if function is defined like that, code will be read by interpreter from top to bottom. Moving function declaration to 2nd line should work.

Comment: While moving the function to the second line would likely work, it'd also redefine the function on every click, which isn't something you want.

Comment: BTW, how its working in chrome, without showing any js error?

Comment: BTW its working when define that toDo, before the call actually thats the normal behaviour

Answer (score 0):

Solution is to just move toDo declaration before first if statement. It will still have exactly this same scope, but function will be available.

Edit just to make it clear

```
$(document.body).on("click", ".btnCheck", function(){
    function toDo () {
       //Do something
    }
    if () {
        //do something
    } else {
        if (pcheck == "online") {
            // Doing some operations and function calling
            toDo();
        } else {
            toDo();  // function calling, HERE SHOWING ERROR IN FIREFOX 
            // ReferenceError: toDo is not defined
        }
    }

});
```

Comment: Depends what he wants to achieve. If function actually needs to be scoped that completely good solution.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this

```
var theFunction = function toDo () {
};
// then to execute it
theFunction();
```

In your case

```
$(document).ready(function(){     
    var theFunction = function toDo () {
        alert();
    };

        var pcheck = "test"
    if (pcheck == "online") {
        theFunction();
    }else{
        theFunction();
    }   
});
```

But you shouldn't do it